# Why chrome.history.onVisited event is fired multiple times on a single visit?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, history, browser-extension

I'm trying to do something when a web browser has loaded a new web page.

my code in background.js is here.

```
chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(function(details) {
  console.log('onVisited is fired: '+details.url);
});
```

Unfortunately, console outputs 'onVisited is fired: xxxxx' multiple times per a single event.

help me. plz.

Comment: The site is probably using history.pushState or replaceState.

Comment: Their URLs should be the same, you might be able to use that.